# How to use int array in typedef struct (C)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

can you please explain how to use int array in typedef struct?

In my header i have code:

```
typedef struct {
    int arr[20];
    int id;
} Test;
```

In some function (where i include my header file) i use:

```
Test tmp = malloc(sizeof(Test));
tmp.id = 1;
//and how to use array arr?
//for example I want add to array -1
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: `tmp.arr[0] = -1`? You would have to keep track of the last index as you can't "add" stuff to arrays. Their size is fixed (unless you use `realloc`)

Comment: I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error after this command.

Comment: The code shown won't compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically

```
Test* tmp = malloc(sizeof(Test));
tmp->id = 1;        //or (*tmp).id = 1;
tmp->arr[0] = 5;    // or (*tmp).arr[0] = 5
                    // any index from 0 to 19, any value instead of 5 (that int can hold)
```

If you do not want to use dynamic memory

```
Test tmp;
tmp.id = 1;      //any value instead of 1 (that int can hold)
tmp.arr[0] = 1;  //any value instead of 1 (that int can hold)
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) in the comments,

```
Test* tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);
```

is better then

```
Test* tmp = malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

Since, to quote [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) *"The former would survive a change in the type definition of `tmp` without any further code changes"*

Comment: `(*tmp).` is quite uncommon, whereas doing `tmp->` instead isn't.

Comment: Als doing `Test * tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp);` instead of `... malloc(sizeof(Test));` would not only be nicer, but also saver.

Comment: @alk how are those different?

Comment: The former would survive a change in the type definition of `tmp` without any further code changes, that's why mentioned "*saver*".

Comment: @alk, thats ok, i edited the answer. But since both the things are on the same line, its quite easy to change both. And the former one looks a little less readable.